# What's the difference between aplay -l and aplay -L?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, alsa, audio-playback

I'm trying to configure my Raspberry Pi (model B) to work as an AirPlay to Bluetooth bridge of sorts. I'm using Shairport-Sync to receive the AirPlay audio successfully, and can get it to output via Alsa to either the built-in minijack or a USB sound card, and I've got Bluetooth mostly-working, but I'm struggling to connect the dots.

I've configured `~/.asoundrc` so I can connect to my Bluetooth speaker successfully, and can play audio via mplayer using the command `mplayer -ao alsa:device=bluetooth audiofile.mp3`, but I can't get any output via aplay.

In trying to get aplay to work too, I've discovered that my Bluetooth audio device appears when I enter the command `aplay -L`, but it doesn't when I do `aplay -l`.

So what's the difference? Why does it show in one but not the other?

I think if I can understand this, I might be able to play audio via aplay on the command line, and if I can do that, I should be able to get Shairport-sync to output to my Bluetooth speakers too!

Can anyone share some knowledge with me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As per the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/aplay) (which should be installed, read `man aplay`):

```
-l, --list-devices
    List all soundcards and digital audio devices
-L, --list-pcms
    List all PCMs defined
```

[PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) is the standard way that uncompressed digital audio is encoded for playback. It may colloquially refer to a source/sink of such a signal ("PCM interface" might be clearer), which usually requires a hardware clock to work, hence they cannot be created arbitrarily.  Some sound cards and devices may have multiple PCMs available.

Conversely, you may have a PCM available to the system which isn't really local.  There's still a clock involved with the timing, but in this case it would be the clock for the transmitter/receiver, which isn't actually a "digital audio device".

This explanation is conjectural on my part, but fits the facts.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly! I checked the manual already and got what you posted, but it didn't really mean a lot to me. So does that mean I need to somehow make my Bluetooth PCM a child of a hardware sound device to get aplay to work, or is that barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Dunno.  Seems like CL's answer is more pragmatic.  You might check the levels with `alsamixer -D xxx` (where xxx is as per CL).

Answer (score 2):

`aplay -l` lists all *hardware* devices, i.e., devices handled by an ALSA kernel driver.
These devices, identified by card number `x` and device number `y`, can be accessed directly with a device name `hw:x,y`. Software plugins that are layered on top of hardware device also accept these numbers, e.g., `plughw:x,y` or `dmix:x`.

`aplay -L` lists the ALSA device names of all hardware and software devices (that are configured to be listed).

To use device name `xxx` with `aplay`, run `aplay -D xxx`.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly! So why is there a distinction between the two? I was indeed trying `aplay -D bluetooth filename.mp3`, which says 'playing raw data' but doesn't actually make any sounds, unlike mplayer. Any ideas what I'm overlooking?

Comment: `aplay` does not support MP3 files.